# Redis as session storage for WordPress in docker

Tags: php, wordpress, session, docker, redis

I've been trying to link Redis with WordPress in docker for a while now, but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM wordpress:latest

ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION 2.2.8

 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yqq unzip git php5-redis
 RUN curl -L -o /tmp/redis.tar.gz https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && rm -r /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && mv phpredis-$PHPREDIS_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis

RUN { \
    echo 'session.save_handler = redis'; \
    echo 'session.save_path = redis:6379'; \
} >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-redis.ini

RUN curl -o /tmp/composer.phar http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar \
  && mv /tmp/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN curl -o /tmp/markdown.zip https://littoral.michelf.ca/code/php-markdown/php-markdown-extra-1.2.8.zip \
  && unzip /tmp/markdown.zip -d /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins

RUN git clone https://github.com/Otto42/simple-twitter-connect.git /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/simple-twitter-connect

RUN rm -rf /tmp/stc.zip && rm -rf /tmp/stc && rm -rf /tmp/markdown.zip

ADD etc/composer.json /usr/src/composer.json

RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN cd /usr/src/ && /usr/local/bin/composer install
RUN chmod -R a+rX /usr/src/wordpress

RUN curl -o /tmp/twentyeleven.zip https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/twentyeleven.2.4.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/twentyeleven.zip -d /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/themes/
RUN rm -rf /tmp/twentyeleven.zip && rm -rf /tmp/dataporten-oauth.zip

COPY feidernd /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/themes/feidernd
COPY wp-redis-user-session-storage.php /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-redis-user-session-storage.php

VOLUME volume/ /var/www/
```

And I'm linking the two containers

```
$ docker run -p 6379:6379 --name redis redis
$ docker run -p 80:80 --link redis:redis --env-file=env.list -t testbuild
```

I have tried to install the Native-PHP-Sessions plugin from Pantheon (https://github.com/pantheon-systems/wp-native-php-sessions), but with no luck.

Anyone with some good advice on how to get the two to link properly?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what's going on from what you've posted. Did you verify redis is working properly by `docker exec ...` to it? Similarly, can you `docker exec` into the WP container and communicate with redis? (You might need to `apt-get install redis-tools` on the WP container.) On a separate note, I would consider externalizing your WP files so you don't have such a complicated build, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

use a docker-compose file instead. then to verify, try to execute a curl from your wordpress container to check that they are linked.

what are you seeing to think they aren't linked correctly?

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Might be redis that's not configured correctly, since I'm getting a constant load when running curl redis:6379, and no answer.